# Angular JS - http.get ignore certificate

Tags: angularjs, angular, http, https

I am just a few hours old to AngularJS and trying to use some opensource code to make it work in my environment.
In our environment, the traffic is encrypted suing TLS. I would like to ignore the security like we do using curl -k

How to ignore TLS certificate while making call to secured TLS URL like we do using curl -k

```
$http.get(https://url:443/metrics).then(function
```

Error which i am getting

```
remote error: tls: handshake failure
```

Comment: Not enough information here. However, Angular runs in a browser and doesn’t deal with network protocols on that level at all.

Comment: In the example above, 'https://url:443/metrics' is over TLS and self signed. So, http.get request fails with tls error. I wanted to skip the tls check

Comment: You’ll need to solve this in the browser.. or the OS even..